# Saving regular SQL result array as an entry in another table do reduce queries number, good idea or not?

Tags: mysql, database, json, gps

I had an idea and I wonder if its completely stupid or a good idea.

I'm working on a web app which analyze GPX tracks and give stats.
Actually I'm storing the coordinates of each points of each tracks in a table, this way :

```
point_id | track_id | lat | lon | else | speed | timestamp
```

and each time I'm selecting entries from this table, I do it by track_id :

```
 SELECT * FROM points WHERE 'track_id'=12
```

And so I'm getting a full array that I then process to get it formatted for example for my map script :

```
[[46.323, 7.543, 1465663049], [46.323, 7.543, 1465663049], [46.323, 7.543, 1465663049]]...
```

Or for my speed graph script :

```
[[1465663049, 9, 12], [1465663049, 9, 12], [1465663049, 9, 12], [1465663049, 9, 12]...
```

But I think that making a query involving hundreds of entries to process them the same way every time is a bit unproductive so I was wondering if I could make a kind of buffer table with my processed results, for example :

```
track_id | map_array | graph_array
```

So I would only have to make one query to get my array, but it means that the field will be quite big as they would need to store thousands of characters an entry.

Maybe a best choice would be to store them in a json datatype field so it can be easily used by my scripts ?

Do you think it is a good idea ?

TL;DR :
Storing gps tracks point in several entries or storing them in a single entry with json datatype ?

Thank you for reading me.

François

Comment: I guess it depends on how often you reuse the data until is becomes invalid (e.g. because the track was modified). Caching will add an overhead (check if exists and is still valid, read/update cache even if never reused, clean up cache), and you have to modify your code, so it has to be worthy.  Accessing the data if you have an index on `track_id` is not that expensive, but cached data will be faster here. If you cache, save as json, the data has no meaning in mysql anyway. If you just have one server, an alternative might be to store it in the filesystem, and store e.g. the filename in db.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The data won't become invalid, that's why I was wondering if I could cache my processed query in the first place. Each track will be created once but read an infinite number of time. So I think I will go with storing my full processed tracks instead of individual points.

Comment: Just to make sure you understood me correctly: Do not store a json field INSTEAD of your table. Store both. Storage is cheap. It should really just be a cache in the traditional sense to prevent you from calculating your value over and over again, but you still should be able to calculate your value over and over again if you wanted to, and you still should be able to store the cache e.g. in the filesystem or the client. It is completely independent from your datamodel. You never know when you might need to calculate something different from that original values.

Comment: Yeah I'v planned to keep a record of both the track points in the database, and the original gpx file in the filesystem. As you said, you never know when you might need to calculate something different from the original values. Thank you for your advices I think I now have my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Solarflare advices and some reflexion I think I have the answer for my own case.

As my queries for tracks will be always identical, it makes no sense to look trough each points it's like always asking the same question when you know the answer.

So here is my database structure I will be using and which I think is the most easy to use and maintain but also the less resource intensive. At least in my own case.

- The gpx files will be decomposed in points that will be stored in the database to be able to have access to the original data.
- In another table, the points will be stored as an array in a text field for quick and simple "one query" access.

My two tables will be something like that :

Original track points :

```
point_id | user_id | track_id | lat | lon | else | speed | timestamp
```

Processed tracks :

```
track_id | user_id | map_array | graph_array
```

I'm not a php or database expert but if I have to query 10 tracks on a page the performance should be different if I have to get 10 * ~600 entries or just 10 entries which doesn't need processing.